# Running App on TV with LG IDE

Tags: wamp, wampserver, lg, smart-tv

I have a LG SMART TV Upgrader LG SP820.

I'm following this instruction trying to run Running an App on TV with LG IDE:

http://developer.lge.com/resource/tv/RetrieveDocDevLibrary.dev

From the TV Browser I get a message:

```
Cannot connect to destination IP address
```

I have also installed WAMPSERVER and with WAMPSERVER I'm able to run successfully the page on localhost.

What could prevent LG SMART TV to connected to my local computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was TV and PC were not on the same Switch (even if in the same network).

Connected TV and PC on the same switch solved the problem

Comment: what do you mean by saying Switch? I got a problem that my TV sometimes connect to my pc, and sometimes ignores its connection requests, i.e. trying to remote debug fails and I left with modal ˜trying to connect to tv˜ open.

Comment: I mean the TV should be connected the same Network Switch of your computer. I hope can helps :-)